# How to interpret Shap summary plot on causal application with X,T,Y?

Tags: statistical-significance, python, inference, causality, shapley-value

I am trying to make sense of how to interpret the following Shap plot given the context of a causal model. See article of relevance: https://towardsdatascience.com/causal-machine-learning-for-econometrics-causal-forests-5ab3aec825a7.

At the end of the article, the following Shap summary plot is shown which is derived by generating the Treatment-Outcome pairs of the model with this code:

```
# code adapted from https://github.com/microsoft/EconML
import shap
from econml.dml import CausalForestDML

# fit causal forest with default parameters 
causal_forest = CausalForestDML()
causal_forest.fit(Y, T, X=X, W=W)

# calculate shap values of causal forest model 
shap_values = causal_forest.shap_values(X)
# plot shap values 
shap.summary_plot(shap_values['Y0']['T0'])
```

[image]

Now, in the sense of a predictive ML model, I would read this as what the impact and relationship of individual features are with respect to my outcome variable. In the case above, I would say that the age of the head of the household (X1) has the highest impact on the loan amount (Y) given. Next, I would say there is that the older the age of the head of the household, the lower the loan amount and vice versa.

**Question**
Now, I am not sure how to interpret this plot with the additional treatment (T). or is this plot showing the relationship/impact of T across all X's and it has nothing to do with Y?

One example would be great if someone could assist with that.

Answer (score 1):

I am actually dealing with the same type of model, and the interpretation is rather not straightforward for me as well. And I haven't found any clear explanation of how this works.

In theory, I believe when you have a causal model, the SHAP values outline the impact of the covariate in the treatment effect over the outcome.

So, in the case of your plot, taking "head_age_bl" as an example, We see a distribution in which the high values are more in the negative direction and the low values in the positive, meaning high values of this feature make the treatment effects on the outcome smaller.

I am also not entirely sure whether this is the case though, so I would also be interested in learning more about it.